# Transaction attributes in lifecycle callback method of singleton session bean

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

Why methods annotated with @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy in singleton session beans with
container managed transactions can have only one of the following transaction attributes:

• REQUIRED

• REQUIRES_NEW

• NOT_SUPPORTED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess because `@PostConstruct` or `@PreDestroy` annotated methods are methods invoked by the container during bean creation or destruction, so making these methods part of mandatory transaction wouldn't make sense (since there are no business methods called before `@PostConstruct`). Same applies for `SUPPORT` type.

You can make the method transactional by itself (so this method becomes atomic) but it can't join other transactions because it is invoked by the container and you have no control over it.